# Redux Form: InitialState from current State

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to build out a form application using redux form.

Currently its working great, but I would like to add default values to show up in my input and can't figure out how to do it.

It should show default values if the user enters a modify post view. (just like here on StackOverflow, when you press edit you can see prev values of your post.)

Currently, I have it built up in two different files one that renders the UI to screen `PostEdit` and a FormComponent: `FormRenderForm`

### PostEdit

```
<Field
  label="Title"
  name="title"
  type="input"
  textType="text"
  currentValue={posts.title}
  component={FormRenderForm}
/>
```

As you can see here it is just a regular `<Field>` Component connected to a custom component were I would like my `currentValue` to be a default value.

---

### ! EDIT !

If I make an modification to my reduxForm im able to get some values but just strings for now not sure how to grab it from state.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ posts }, ownProps) => {
  console.log(posts)
  return {
    posts: posts.filter(
      item => item.id === ownProps.match.params.postId && item.deleted !== true
    )[0],
    /* This initialValues seams to not be working */
    initialValues: {
      title: posts[0] !== undefined ? posts[0].title : '',
      body: posts[0] !== undefined ? posts[0].body : '',
    },
  }
}
```

Console.log from mapStateToProps

```
[
  0: {
    author: "thingtwo"
    body: "Everyone says so after all."
    category: "react"
    commentCount: 0
    deleted: false
    id: "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd"
    timestamp: 1467166872634
    title: "Stackoverflow is the best place to learn React"
    voteScore:6
    }
]
```

InitialValues added to reduxForm

```
export default withRouter(
  reduxForm({
    form: 'EditPost',
    validate,
    /* 
      This makes it pop up as myTitle and myBody but cant grab state 
      here.

      initialValues: { title: 'myTitle', body: 'myBody' },
    */
  })(connect(mapStateToProps, { getPosts, editPost })(PostEdit))
)
```

---

### FormRenderForm

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const FormRenderForm = props => {
  return (
    <div className="field">
      <div className="control">
        <label className="label">{props.label}</label>
        <props.type
          className={props.type}
          type={props.textType}

          /* defaultValue={props.currentValue } */

          {...props.input}
        />
        {props.meta.touched &&
          props.meta.error && (
            <p className="error">
              <i className="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true" />
              {props.meta.error}
            </p>
          )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

FormRenderForm.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  textType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  input: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  meta: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default FormRenderForm
```

Best Regards, Petter

Comment: have you tried removing  {...props.input}  ?

Comment: there is a good article here ... https://redux-form.com/7.1.1/examples/initializefromstate/

Comment: Hi, @jojojohn I have tried to remove {...props.input} and do value = {props.currentValue} that gave me the values but it was not changable

Comment: @jojojohn Have tried following that article but looks like my mapstatetoprops won't work as shown in the articale

Comment: try   {...field.input}   instead

Comment: hum didn't work. This is how my props look when entering `FormRenderForm` https://imgur.com/a/s9V5n